# How can I retry navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition more than one time to get real customer location

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code to test if my customer is near or far from my center (at least 2 km)...
My problem is ... in some mobiles it takes some seconds to get the real customer GPS location (depends on their device quality), that's why I want to try more than one time, and I want to wait some seconds before giving an error message. Lets say I want to try 5 time in 30 seconds to get the real location, and after that I want to display an error message.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    var Options = { enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 0, timeout: 60000 };
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(Success, Error, Options);

    function Success(position) {
        if (haversineDistance([position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude], [45.896328,28.3350241], false) < 2) {
            alert('ok you are here');
        }
        else {
            alert('sorry you are not here');

        }

    }


    function Error() {
        alert('error');
    }

    function haversineDistance(coords1, coords2, isMiles) {

        function toRad(x) {
            return x * Math.PI / 180;
        }

        var lon1 = coords1[0];
        var lat1 = coords1[1];

        var lon2 = coords2[0];
        var lat2 = coords2[1];

        var R = 6371; // km

        var x1 = lat2 - lat1;
        var dLat = toRad(x1);
        var x2 = lon2 - lon1;
        var dLon = toRad(x2)
        var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
          Math.cos(toRad(lat1)) * Math.cos(toRad(lat2)) *
          Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        var d = R * c;

        if (isMiles) d /= 1.60934;

        return d;
    }


});
```

Comment: any answer @PeteLe ?

Comment: any one have any info please let us know?